# Passing specific ArrayList data, of Selected Item of Listview, from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

JSON String:

```
    [{
      "name": "Gun Fu: Stickman 2",
      "price": "4",
      "rating": "4.4",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "13"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "2"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "61"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Call of Duty: Heroes",

    "price": "1.2",
    "rating": "4.4",
           "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "25"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "25"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "50"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Batman Arkham",

    "price": "0",
    "rating": "4.2",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "33"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "30"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "37"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Minecraft",

    "price": "4.3",
    "rating": "4.5",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "60"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "3"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "37"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Clash of Clans",

    "price": "0",
    "rating": "4.6",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "20"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "25"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "55"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Flappy Bird",

    "price": "10",
    "rating": "3.7",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "10"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "15"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "75"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Hitman: Sniper",

    "price": "2",
    "rating": "4.8",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "20"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "40"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "40"
        }
    ]
},
{

    "price": "4.3",
    "rating": "4.8",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "15"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "70"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "15"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Where's My Perry?",

    "price": "0",
    "rating": "4.6",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "33"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "33"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "34"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Cut the Rope 2",

    "price": "6",
    "rating": "4.2",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "40"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "30"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "30"
        }
    ]
},
{

    "price": "0",
    "rating": "4.4",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "83"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "7"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "10"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "TRANSFORMERS",

    "price": "0",
    "rating": "4.0",

    "demographic": [
        {
            "country": "India",
            "percentage": "1"
        },
        {
            "country": "China",
            "percentage": "0"
        },
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "percentage": "99"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Now what i need here is:

1. Getting List of Game Names into the listview.*(I have already done)*
2. After clicked on any item of the game listview,its related country and percentage into demographic tag should be displayed into new activity.*(Yet to do)*

**Please suggest some useful and less memory consumption tips to do so.**

Comment: Passing the values as extras in the intent that you use to start the new activity?

Comment: Roi Divon Please check my updated post below,i hav added my code and the result i m getting.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code i am using :

In SourceActivity:
game is ModelClass object.

```
    intent.putExtra("country",game.getCountry());
    intent.putExtra("percentage",String.valueOf(game.getPercentage()));
```

In ReceiverActivity:

```
  game_country=getIntent().getStringExtra("country");
  game_percentage=getIntent().getStringExtra("percentage");
  Log.d("NewCountry:",game_country);  // show in logcat//
  Log.d("\nNewPercentage:", game_percentage);  // show in logcat//
```

Result:

```
  07-28 07:47:36.956    2453-2453/? D/NewCountry:﹕ USA
  [ 07-28 07:47:36.984  2453: 2453 D/NewPercentage: ]   37
```

Rather than showing all related more countries with their related percentage.

Comment: What are you expecting to get?

Comment: @RoiDivon I need to display all three country names with their percentage into Receiver Activity, on clicked item(Game Name) that is into my ListView in Source Activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can parsing data to new activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, YOURACTIVITY.class);
 intent.putExtra("key", name);

 startActivity(intent);
```

[read this line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21038627/1651200) for more the code

Comment: andiyulistyo thanks for this suggestion -----i already had tried the same but it is showing all data of all items of all country and percentage rather then showing specific/related country and percentage of clicked item only.

Answer (score 0):

Doing so the best practice is to use parcelable objects. Sending parcelable objects android has a faster support to communicate between different components. [Have a look](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)